# How to obtain the same random sample from a list in Python

Tags: python, random

I have a small script to get a random sample from a list, however I want to always get the same list whenever I run this script. How should I do this?

My code currently is as follows, however each time that I run the script, I get a different sample.

```
import random

def SampleWithoutRepetition(population, sampleSize):
    random.seed(100)
    result =  random.sample(set(
        map(lambda attribute: attribute, population)), sampleSize)
    print(f"result: {result}")

population = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']

SampleWithoutRepetition(population, 4)
```

Comment: In that case it will not be random. What's the point of using random for this?

Comment: Well this script is just a small part of a larger problem, however I am trying to debug something and to do so I wanted to set a specific seed and get the same list every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `set()` is an unordered container which does not preserve the order of your `population`. Like this you choose exactly the same sample from different populations each time the set is re-instantiated. Use `list()` instead, or directly use

```
result =  random.sample([x for x in population], sampleSize)
```

In the `[]` expansion you can calculate the attribute as you probably intended with the `lambda`. So your script could look like this:

```py
import random
random.seed(100)

def SampleWithoutRepetition(population, sampleSize):
    func = lambda attribute: attribute
    return random.sample([func(x) for x in population], sampleSize)

population = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']

print(SampleWithoutRepetition(population, 4))
```

If you keep the `random.seed` in the function, it will return the same sample each time you call the *function*, if you put it outside, you receive the same sample each time you call the *script*, as requested in your question.